# MS Access Pop New Data in table

Tags: ms-access

I have a small DB that is used to add information from a form collected information about people calling. Namber Number Decrisption Time and date to call back.

Use this is entered I would like a pop up message bout in rew recorders that need to be called. can some please help me here. Thanks

Comment: Nice t-shirt Steve, but your questions has bad typos and doesn't make sense.   You probably need to filter the form to show those needing a call back.

Comment: When the reception gets an incoming call, she is putting call information in the form Return Calls, which all goes into returncall table. I would like there to be a pop up alert or message box that tells me there are active calls in the table that need returned. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope these pointers might help

You will need to use a timer event to trigger code that opens a recordset using SQL to count the number of records in the table that which are calls needing to be returned.

If the count is >=1 then give the user a popup form message.

See

[timer events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192530.aspx)

[openrecordsets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820966.aspx)